# Render 4 different cameras on 4 different monitors (unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiple-monitors

I have 4 different cameras in a Unity Scene, I want to render those 4 perspectives in 4 monitors. Please guide me.
(You are free to downvote me to oblivion but please at least answer the question.)
Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the display in the Camera GameObject's property. Display 0 is the main screen, Display 1 the second etc...

The attribute is called "targetDisplay".

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html